# How to get info from DER x509 certificate in javascript

Tags: javascript, x509certificate, signing

I am working with browser token signing, with internet explorer I can sign a text with my certificate where I am using a Gemalto reader card.
And my problem is I can't obtain the certificate info, as it's in a DER (hex) format like mention below: 
`[Certificate return on IE 11][2]`
Hence to parse it I use node-x509, and when I test it (npm test) it works fine, but when I test it in the browser with a javascript code([plugin test](https://github.com/open-eid/browser-token-signing/blob/master/plugin-test.html)) , I am facing problem with `"require('x509')" : require undefined`

```js
const x509 = require('x509');
var cert = x509.parseCert('mycertif'),
```

how to parse it with javascript?? or how to resolve the undefined "require"??

Comment: do you have a node_modules folder in your project, and is the x509 module installed there?